# Bars of a ggplot disappear when geom_errorbar is added

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm building a bar plot with ggplot2 and the code works fine until I add error bars with geom_errorbar. My dataset consists of two factors [Sex(two levels) and Time(seven levels)] and several dependent continuous variables. ABA.mean is the mean ABA.se is the standard error.

[Data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXm56.png)

Here's the code for the plot (I made sure Sex and Time were factors).

```
p<- ggplot(data=sex.data1, aes(x=Time, y=ABA.mean, ymin=ABA.mean-ABA.se, ymax=ABA.mean+ABA.se))

p1<-p + geom_bar(aes(fill=Sex), stat="identity",
                       position="dodge")+ geom_errorbar(aes(color=Sex), position="dodge")
```

And here's the plot:

output of bar plot with error bars:

[image]

Here's also some data (not showing all data to facilitate comprehension)

```
dput(sex.data1)

structure(list(Sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor"),Time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L,4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7"), class = "factor"), RWC.mean = c(46.87233333, 56.971, 
5.884, 6.562666667, 10.30466667, 80.95266667, 79.22333333, 
72.04366667, 80.87166667, 77.15266667, 6.962, 8.733, 86.051, 
84.586), ABA.mean = c(9.532666667, 322.969, 28.4, 30.15066667, 
45.529, 46.298, 18.60933333, 13.838, 46.31466667, 202.3803333, 
10.5005, 16.637, 17.64466667, 6.595333333),RWC.se = c(6.428766324,19.39234553, 2.152576673, 0.328793924, 1.972588936, 1.542849888,4.434089322, 8.443211501, 3.087210679, 5.593021853, 0.574815043,NA, 9.684611522, 1.546559515), ABA.se = c(2.654699878, 89.919,11.59730729, 10.52325178, 24.42691451, 29.76969347, 8.154232119,4.295445767, 21.57449026, 132.4679665, 1.1755, NA, 9.29181176,3.315272605)
```

However, when I compute the plot without the geom_errobar, the bars appear.

```
p<-ggplot(sex.data1, aes(x=Time, y=ABA.mean, fill=Sex))
p+geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

I'm guessing there's something wrong with the code of geom_errorbar.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share some data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: I've included it in the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your plotting code looks fine to me, but your dput formatting was a bit strange. I had fix the syntax in the data, so it seems like that might have been the issue (ie format/syntax of your input data). The code you posted produces the plot just fine:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=sex.data1, aes(x=Time, y=ABA.mean, ymin=ABA.mean-ABA.se, ymax=ABA.mean+ABA.se)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=Sex), stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(color=Sex), position="dodge")
```

[image]

data:

```
sex.data1 <- data.frame(
  Sex = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", 'M', "M", "M", 'M', "M"),
  Time = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"),
  RWC.mean = c(46.87233333, 56.971, 5.884, 6.562666667, 10.30466667, 80.95266667, 79.22333333, 72.04366667, 80.87166667, 77.15266667, 6.962, 8.733, 86.051, 84.586),
  ABA.mean = c(9.532666667, 322.969, 28.4, 30.15066667, 45.529, 46.298, 18.60933333, 13.838, 46.31466667, 202.3803333, 10.5005, 16.637, 17.64466667, 6.595333333),
  RWC.se = c(6.428766324,19.39234553, 2.152576673, 0.328793924, 1.972588936, 1.542849888,4.434089322, 8.443211501, 3.087210679, 5.593021853, 0.574815043,NA, 9.684611522, 1.546559515),
  ABA.se = c(2.654699878, 89.919,11.59730729, 10.52325178, 24.42691451, 29.76969347, 8.154232119,4.295445767, 21.57449026, 132.4679665, 1.1755, NA, 9.29181176,3.315272605))
```

Comment: If I'm correct, the code you posted is the same as the one I was using. If it works for you but not for me I don't know what's going on... I restarted the session and tried it again and the same error occurs. Howver I tried with changing the structure of the error from ggplot to geom_errorbar and it works now. `ggplot(data=sex.data1, aes(x=Time, y=ABA.mean, fill=Sex)) + 
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ABA.mean-ABA.se, ymax=ABA.mean+ABA.se),
                                position=position_dodge())`

Comment: Hmm. You shouldn't have to define your aes mapping again in geom_errorbar, which is what you are saying fixed the plot. Have you tried using my code and data? Have you tried using my code and your data?